# Is there more monosyllabic lexis in the English Language than polysyllabic lexis?

Tags: word-choice

In terms of words in the actual dictionary are there more monosyllabic words or more polysyllabic words?

Comment: There are far more polysyllabic words, because there are far more polysyllabic possibilities. There are fewer than 5000 monosyllabic words in Modern English.

Comment: I'd say it's 100% certain there are *far* more polysyllabic words than monosyllabic ones, regardless of whether we ignore things like ***writing*** as simply an "inflected" variant of monosyllabic ***write***

Comment: Yeah, there's not that much inflection left. I happen to know there's fewer than 5000 because I have a database of them, and I was surprised to find out how few there were, too. But it makes sense when you think about it; are there more small numbers or more large numbers?

Comment: @John: I'm not sure exactly how one defines *lexis/lexicon*, but I can imagine saying that "inflection" itself, for example, could be deconstructed into **flex** plus prefix **in-** and suffix **-tion** (allowing for a certain etymological looseness). On the numbers front, there are more numbers above 9 than there are single-digit numbers, but they're all *constructed* from that base set (if that's the way OP sees the question).

Comment: That's morphemes. @Georgia was asking about words in a dictionary. There are of course lots of dead short words in the OED -- practically every possible monosyllable in English has been used to mean something or other at some time -- but the number of actual words in American English is well under 5000. Actually, it's under 4000; when Rich Rhodes and I were making up our simplex word database, we found we could add all the words with a dozen or so unstressed meaningless endings (like _silly, blanket, simmer_) to expand the data available.

Comment: Monosyllabic words may be less numerous, but are they less frequent? A side question, really.

Comment: Perhaps he didn't consider it newsworthy, but Prof Lawler has published his monosyllable database on his [website](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/) -- it's a 7MB zip file.

Comment: "But it makes sense when you think about it; are there more small numbers or more large numbers?" -- @JohnLawler. Everything you've said is good except for this. Please don't think this way.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "Are there more small integers or more large integers?"

Comment: @JohnLawler why don't you post your (already quite complete, with evidence) comments as an answer?